# Select a TreeItem in a tree using WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, tree, windowbuilder

So am trying to make a project where the user can select from a tree a `TreeItem` called `Category` , and by that category, a table will sort so it matches it.

The problem is that am using `WindowBuilder` in Eclipse and I don't see an event that says so, or a way to make it that the point where the cursor is aiming at, is the Item selected (when clicking of course) .

The other thing is that, is there any way to use `Jforms` using `WindowBuilder`? I think there is a big difference between them.

And for information, I already searched in the net and all I found is solutions about `TreeView` which first I am not using and second I tested it and still it doesn't work.

This is the Code I used so I can detect the selected `TreeItem` when I click but it does not work either:

```
    Tree tree = new Tree(Frame, SWT.BORDER);
    tree.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            TreeItem item = 
        tree.getItem(Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation());
            if(item != null) {
               ...
```

Comment: ( tree.getItem(Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation()); )
This si the line where I select the TreeItem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected `TreeItem` from the `item` property of `SelectionEvent`:

```
tree.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        // get the selected item
        TreeItem item = (TreeItem) e.item;

        if(item != null) {
           ...
```

Comment: Dude , you just saved my life (letterally) . But still I have many many questions ...
1- What si an event and a listener , how do they work ?
2- Is there any course you can tell me about so i can learn to use them ?

And finelly , Thank you very much !

Comment: 1. events are sent after user interactions (for example selecting an item, pushing a button etc), listeners intercept events so you can do something when that happens (that is why you used a `SelectionListener`, to intercept the selection event of the tree)

2. this is part of `SWT`, so google `SWT` tutorials and read the `SWT` documentation

Comment: Thank you very much , I will look for SWT .